# What is difference between android 2.3 vs android 4.0

Tags: android

what is the difference between 2.3 version and 4.0 version from a programmer point of view, for instance what are the library i would be missing out, is it the fragments only are other thing as well.

Thanks

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/155292), and [Stack Overflow is not a List for All Things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/155292).

Comment: Good question. That would save a lot of separate question here in stackoverflow and save a lot of time to programmers in looking for solving version differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice list [here](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/android-versions-comparison) (although it's not as programmer intense as the official SDK release notes)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite many noteworthy changes! I recommend to read the release notes: http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html